# How can I unhide the http:// in Firefox 7?

Tags: url, firefox

I've recently switched to FF7 through the Aurora PPA on KUbuntu.  For whatever reason, they've decided to start **removing http:// from the address bar**:

[image: Missing http]

Whenever I edit a link (so that I can paste it in a question or answer here on Stack Exchange) the `http://` is missing when I go to paste it!?!! I've searched through the preferences.  I can't find anything that will undo it -- short of going back to the non-beta browser.  I've also google searched for this and *oddly enough* the only thing I could find was a request to *enable* this behavior, [asked here on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/6934/hide-the-http-in-web-browsers/303277#303277). That said, I really wanted to keep using FF7 on the computers I maintain because of its greatly improved memory performance.

Comment: I should note that Chrome also hides http://, however it has a special semantic - when you select and copy any initial part of the URL, it will add http:// to the resulting paste. I suggest you ask the Firefox devs to do the same.

Comment: Yes - you should file a bug report at http://bugzilla.mozilla.org .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go into `about:config`, set `browser.urlbar.trimURLs` to `false`